# De normalize data in R

Tags: r, normalization, knn

I apply normalization function to my data with this code:

`normalize <- function(x) { return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))}`

Then I applied the function to my data, only for numeric variables.

`bankfull[,c(1,6,10,12:15)]= as.data.frame(lapply(bankfull[,c(1,6,10,12:15)], normalize))`

Can someone help me to revert normalization?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: once you've done this you've lost the information you need to revert, unless you've saved the per-column min/max values.  You should consider the `scale()` function, which can be adapted to do the kind of normalization you want, and which stores the normalization shift/scale values as attributes of the data ...

Comment: Thank you very much, but how I can do it ? @BenBolker

Comment: If you haven't retained the values of `min(x), max(x)` is is impossible to go backwards. If you have retained those values, solving for the original `x` is just junior high math (solve for `x` in `y = (x-a)/(b-a)` with `a` and `b` known so `x = (b-a)*y+a` ). Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you @JohnColeman, I didn't retain the values... how can I solve my problem then?

Comment: Flat out impossible. You have lost information.

Comment: @JohnColeman Do you have any advice for me to help me with this? Can I change something in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: I don't know what your goal is, so I have no advice about how to achieve it. The reason why it is impossible is that different data sets can give rise to the same set of normalized data.

Answer (score 0):

There's a package `DMwR` that unscales sets of values and is worth a shot, even though there are pitfalls to watch out for like John mentioned in the comments. For example, with 100 observations normally distributed with mean of 5 and stdev of 1:

```
library(DMwR)
a <- rnorm(100,5,1)
hist(a)
```

[image]

```
b <- scale(a)
c <- DMwR::unscale(b,b)
```

Now you can compare the values by subtracting `a-c` (you get all nearly-zeroes) or plotting a vs c (which shows the equivalents):

[image]

Comment: this is nice but doesn't work when the scaling is done in a non-standard way (i.e. with center=sapply(cols,min),scale=sapply(cols, function(x) diff(range(x)))